# Finding the length of two sides of a right triangle given only the area

Tags: geometry

Leg $XY$ of the right triangle is twice as long as leg $YZ.$  If the area of the triangle is $36cm^2$, what is the length, in cm, of leg $XY?$

I figured the answer out by applying $A= \dfrac{1}{2} (b \times h)$.  $36 = \dfrac{1}{2} (b x h).$  Knowing that one leg is twice the length of the other leg, I just used $12$ and $6$ as I knew when multiplied it equals $72$ (before being multiplied by $1/2$).  What is the correct formula for finding the answer to this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said $ \frac{1}{2} * b * h $

$ \frac{1}{2} * b * 2b = 36 $

$ b^2 = 36 $

$ b =6 $

This implies $ h = 12 $ as $ h = 2b $

Comment: Thank you, Harish!  I knew I was missing something!